# Can't upload to a FTP server in PHP from a server, but works from another server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I have a problem with my script.
I created a website in Infomaniak (Shared host)
The PHP script send a file to a distant FTP server.

Then, i changed to another host (shared too): Swisscenter.
It doesn't work from that server

It's the same script, with the same logins.
There is no IP whitelist on the destination server

I tested with PHP 5.6 and 7.0, no changes

Here's the error: https://pastebin.com/ZSyVLtsF

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
ErrorException in FTP.php line 47:
ftp_put(): Opening data channel for file transfer.
in FTP.php line 47
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'ftp_put(): Opening data channel for file transfer.', '/website/website.ch/src/app/FTPManager/FTP.php', '47', array('remote_file' => 'src/storage/path/test.TXT', 'file' => 'commande/test.TXT'))
at ftp_put(resource, 'commande/test.TXT', 'src/storage/path/test.TXT', '2') in FTP.php line 47
at FTP->upload('src/storage/path/test.TXT', 'commande/test.TXT') in AdminController.php line 174
at AdminController->sendOrderFtp(object(Order)) in AdminController.php line 124
at AdminController->validateOrderPost(object(Request), 'test')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminController), 'validateOrderPost'), array(object(Request), 'id' => 'test')) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('validateOrderPost', array(object(Request), 'id' => 'test')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AdminController), object(Route), 'validateOrderPost') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AdminController), object(Route), object(Request), 'validateOrderPost') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\AdminController', 'validateOrderPost') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AuthenticateWithBasicAuth.php line 38
at AuthenticateWithBasicAuth->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthenticateWithBasicAuth), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ViewFiller.php line 37
at ViewFiller->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ViewFiller), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Language.php line 36
at Language->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Language), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I don't understand why it works on the first host, and not whith the second
Any idea ?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is the PHP class for FTP:

```
namespace App\FTPManager;


class FTP
{
    protected $host;
    protected $port;
    protected $timeout;
    protected $connection;
    protected $mode = FTP_BINARY;// FTP_ASCII;

    public function __construct($host, $port = 21, $timeout = 90)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getConnection()
    {
        if (!$this->connection) {
            $this->connection = ftp_connect($this->host, $this->port, $this->timeout);
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }


    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        return ftp_login($this->getConnection(), $username, $password);
    }

    public function upload($remote_file, $file)
    {
        return ftp_put($this->getConnection(), $file, $remote_file, $this->mode);
    }

    public function download($file, $remote_file)
    {
        return ftp_get($this->getConnection(), $remote_file, $file, $this->mode);
    }

    public function close()
    {
        ftp_close($this->connection);
        $this->connection = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that your web host blocks PHP from making outgoing connections on port 21? Many hosts will block PHP from doing such operations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
i contacted them but they don't block the port

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it's updated, thanks

Comment: So `ftp_rawlist` works, but `ftp_put` fails? + Do you have an access to FTP server logs?

Comment: Now there's no `ftp_pasv`. And this is not [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to ask ftp logs.

But, ftp_pasv is to enable the passive mode, and the FTP server is not passive. It works in local environement, and in a server in Infomaniak, so I don't think it's a script issue

Comment: the connexion is working, but it fails at put

Comment: There's no `ftp_pasv` in the code you have posted. Again, we need [mcve]. You have posted some class, without showing us how you use it, so it's neither *complete*, nor *verifiable*. Moreover, we are really interested in *minimal* code, what usually rules out use of classes.

Answer (score 1):

use `ftp_pasv();` just check this link https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_ftp_pasv.asp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i'm already using it
The code works, I think it's more a server-side problem